# How to wrap up images together?

Tags: graphics

I would like to do something like shown in the following image. That is I like to wrap up 15 images in the following fashion.
How can I do that please? 
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty and not quite perfect:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\raggedleft
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Some text}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
}

\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Some other text}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
}

\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Some third text}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}%
}

\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\subcaptionbox{}[2cm]{}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}[2cm]{}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}[2cm]{}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}[2cm]{}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}[2cm]{}\hfill
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fboxsep}

\caption{Bla bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```